# Reflections get origin class/interface of a method

Tags: java

I am having a problem returning the interface that declares a method using reflection.

Example:

```
package B;

B interface {
   public void save () ;
}

package A;
import b.B;

class A implements B {

    public void save () {

    }
}
```

when I call `A.class.getDeclaredMethods();`
it returns the `save()` method , ok.

Now how can I return the name of the interface B , where the method was declared? `method.getClass()` returns Class A.

Comment: `A.getInterfaces()` is what you might want. Maybe combine this with `getDeclaredMethods` on the interfaces you get.

Comment: short answer - you can't. there are two different java.lang.Methods save() - one in A and one in B. you can try to detect inheritance somehow though

Comment: The method wasn't "created" in interface B, an interface can only declare a method signature, it's like a shopping list. Therefore you can ask which interfaces declare that method (because there could be multiple ones), or you can ask which class **implemented** the method (in this case, the answer is `A`)

Comment: Of course if you could tell what the problem you're trying to solve is, it may turn out that a different solution is better.